# How to work unique key constraint with JPA annotations in my springboot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

How to work multi-column constraint with JPA annotations in my springboot project?
I'm trying to introduce a multi-key constraint on a JPA-mapped entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student_Master",uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id","sr_no.", "roll_no"})
    })
public class StudentMaster implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer sId;// id same
    @Column(name = "sr_no.", length = 5,nullable = false,unique = true)//not null and sr no. should be unique
    private Integer srNo;
    @Column(name = "roll_no", length = 10,nullable = false,unique = true)
    private Integer rollNo;
```

Basically `(id, sr_no,roll_no)` pair should be unique, but I only found a way to say that id should be unique.

I have also declare unique constraints using the `@Table(uniqueConstraints = ...)` annotation in your entity class.

But it's didn't work because entry the duplicate roll no and srNo also with different user.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to create an `Embedded class`, which contains your keys and reference it in your `StudentMaster`

For this you need `@EmbeddedId` in your Entity and `@Embeddable` over your key class:

```java
@Embeddable
public class MyKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer sId;// id same
    @Column(name = "sr_no.", length = 5, nullable = false, unique = true)//not null and sr no. should be unique
    private Integer srNo;
    @Column(name = "roll_no", length = 10, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer rollNo;

    /** getters and setters **/
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class StudentMaster implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyKey myKey;
}
```

---

Or a way without having the embedded class you can use `@IdClass(MyKey.class)`.
Now you can use the `@Id` over your key attributes

```java
public class MyKey implements Serializable {
    private Integer sId;
    private Integer srNo;
    private Integer rollNo;

    /** getters and setters **/
}
```

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MyKey.class)
public class StudentMaster implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer sId;// id same
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sr_no.", length = 5, nullable = false, unique = true)//not null and sr no. should be unique
    private Integer srNo;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "roll_no", length = 10, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer rollNo;
}
```